# Why is hook_js_alter() function calling twice?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, themes

Inside template.php file, I made the following function:

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$javascript) {
print "Hello World!!!";
}
```

Just for testing purpose, I tried to print a text "Hello World!!!" in the above function. It displayed the output "Hello World!!!" twice.

**Why is it displaying the output twice ?**

Answer (score 0):

Because [`drupal_get_js()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_get_js/7) is called twice... maybe because the theme or a module implement `hook_process_html()`, add some JavaScript using `drupal_add_js()` and then re-invoke `$variables['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();`.